# Setuptools Subpackages with clean Namespace

Tags: python, namespaces, setuptools, software-distribution

I'm using setuptools 40.8.0 under python 3.7.2 to package together some modules and packages in order to make them available system-wide. My goal is to have a clean namespace, where functions are bundled together in functional units.

My folder structure looks like this:

```
mymodule
|  setup.py
|  mymodule
 -  | __init__.py
  - |package_foo
     - __init__.py
     - some_script.py
```

setup.py:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(name='mymodule',
      version='1.0',
      packages=find_packages(),
      zip_safe=False)
```

top level `__init__.py`:

```
from . import package_foo
```

second level `__init__.py`:

```
from .some_script import some_function
```

(I am actually not sure, why the first dot is needed in the imports but I don't seem to make it workable without.)

Now, if I do

```
import mymodule
```

I have `mymodule.package_foo.some_function` in my namespace (which I want), but also `mymodule.package_foo.some_script` (which I don't want). I could add a line in the second level `__init__.py` deleting `some_script` by doing

```
del some_script
```

but that doesn't feel right. Is there another, more elegant way to achieve what I'm trying? Or is it good practice to leave `some_script` in the namespace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround that works for me. If the module name starts with an underscore, it's not included in the namespace automatically. I changed `some_script.py` to `_some_script.py` and the import statements as well.